# django custom forms select tag

Tags: django, forms

I have a a form that I want to output as custom HTML. My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from cdrs.models import Localitymayor

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    genus = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Locality.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup').exclude(islandgroup="n/a").order_by('islandgroup'))
    island_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Locality.objects.values_list('islandname', flat=True).distinct('islandname').exclude(islandname="n/a").order_by('islandname'))
```

In the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) it demonstrates how to output custom html. However the template code below obviously doesn't work for the select fields:

```
<form action="/search/" method="post">
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.genus.errors }}
    <label for="id_genus">Genus:</label>
    {{ form.genus }}
</div>
...
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.island_group.errors }}
    <label for="id_island_group">Island Group:</label>
    {{ form.island_group }}
</div>
...
</form>
```

How do I control the output of select fields for my ModelChoiceFields?

Comment: here you have a good starting point : http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change how Django renders list items you need to override that field's widget.

See the [Customizing widget instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) in the documentation.

And [Overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets).

Finally, if this doesn't give you enough control, you can write your own custom widget.  Here is an [example of a custom widget](http://www.huyng.com/archives/django-custom-form-widget-for-dictionary-and-tuple-key-value-pairs/661/) for working with key-value pairs.  However, the only part you should be concerned with is the `render()` method.  You could extend a built in list widget, override the `render()` method and make it spit out the html you want.

Comment: Yes - this helped alot. I chose to customize the widgets which gives as much control over the html as I need. The  `Widget.attrs` argument proved especially useful.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose you could construct the html yourself.

```
<select name="{{ form.island_group.name }}">
    {% for instance in form.island_group.field.queryset %}
        <option value="{{ instance.pk }}">{{ instance.name }} yarr</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```